Why Guard in Angular shows authorization page for a fraction of a second?
I have a group of routes that are under 'auth.guard.ts':
async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
const user = await this.authStorageService.getUserFromToken();

  if (user) {
    return true;
  } else {
  await this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}

and if I'm authorized, I'm on a router under this guard, then when I refresh the page, I see the login page for a fraction of a second (if I change it to any other page, it will display the specified page also for a fraction of a second). Here's an example in the video (before the loader):
example
All I was able to google was the advice to do this:
return this.router.createUrlTree(['/login'])
But it didn't help. How to fix it?

The advice was correct. Do not call navigate in the guard. Instead simply return the UrlTree where you want to navigate.
Otherwise a new navigation happens before the guard returns and that's what you don't want to happen - or await it.
async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
const user = await this.authStorageService.getUserFromToken();

  if (user) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return this.router. createUrlTree(['/login']);
  }
}


This solution does not work, the login page is still visible.

This answer solves an issue with your code, but a different one.
Your problem is not connected to the guard return value. Instead before the guard awaits the getUserFromToken a default content in the router outlet is displayed. That seems to be the login page.

remove await when you want to navigate
try this instead:
 async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const user = await this.authStorageService.getUserFromToken();

    if (user) {
       return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }


That didn't help either.

Could you try using a observable instead
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    // this.authStorageService.getUserFromToken().pipe( // also try  this!
    return from(this.authStorageService.getUserFromToken()).pipe( 
        tap((user: any) => {
            if(!user) {
                 return this.router.createUrlTree(['/login']);
            }
            return false;
        }) 
    );
}


Tried the commented solution, same result.
Tried the uncommented solution, error:
TS2416: Property 'canActivate' in type 'MainGuard' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CanActivate'.   Type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => Promise<Observable<false | UrlTree>>' is not assignable to type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => MaybeAsync<GuardResult>'.
